# VSCode - Why tsconfig.json must be in the root directory to get autocomplete?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code, typescript1.8

According to the Typescript documentation

> The presence of a tsconfig.json file in a directory indicates that the
>   directory is the root of a TypeScript project. The tsconfig.json file
>   specifies the root files and the compiler options required to compile
>   the project.

In my understanding, this means that I can have some application structure like below

```
+-- app
|  +-- src
|    +-- controllers 
|      +-- AppCtrl.ts 
|    +-- application.ts
|    +-- tsconfig.json
|  +-- assets
```

I noticed that the only way to get autocomplete for new `.ts` files is to create another `tsconfig.json` at my root directory, like

```
+-- app
+-- tsconfig.json    
|  +-- src
|    +-- controllers 
|      +-- AppCtrl.ts 
|    +-- application.ts
```

In the first structure I can get autocomplete if I **reload the IDE after creating new ts files**.

Is there some configuration needed in vscode to get the first structure working or this is wrong?

**UPDATE**: I'm not getting autocomplete with the file in the root directory opened too. Restarting the IDE seems to fix it, but's not an option for every new file created...

[image: vscode autocomplete error]

Comment: Do you have any additional typescript extensions installed?

Comment: Also, in your second layout above, did you mean for the `tsconfig.json` to  be at the same level as `app` or `src`?

Comment: @seairth, no additional extensions for typescript, but I have the EditorConfig installed. In my second layout I put the json file in the root directory, same level as app folder.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you opening a vscode issue at github?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the Editor Config plugin is interfering with the autocomplete. Having the `.editorconfig` file in the project breaks the feature for new files.

I also tested the `tsconfig.json` in the first application structure without editorconfig file and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode, the Folder you open is the root folder. As described in your quoted text, tsconfig.json must be in that folder. It's that simple.

Comment: Even in the root folder vscode is messing up. Autocomplete is working for new files only after a reload in the IDE.

Comment: Also root for me in this scenario is the main script directory. I may want to open an application folder that have css and html files like in the first example.